# What's means of each part of JMS message ID?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

A JMS message ID looks like this `ID:10.77.42.209-4280-1477454185311-1:1:1391:1:1`. The whole string is divided by "-" and ":" into several parts.

It is obviously that one part represents the IP address of the producer, some part may represent the message ID. But what's means of others?

So my question is what's means of each parts?

*Use ActiveMQ and did not custom the message ID*

Answer (score 5):

**JMSMessageID is unique string and the generation logic is up to the JMS provider.**

The below is JMSMessageID definition taken from [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-5904-10/816-5904-10.pdf):

> A JMSMessageID is a String value which should function as a unique key
>   for identifying messages in a historical repository. The exact scope
>   of uniqueness is provider defined.

**As you are interested in ActiveMQ, it consists of:**

```
HostName + "-" + Port + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "-" + sequenceNumber
```

You can refer the complete code [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/util/IdGenerator.java) for ActiveMQ Id generator logic.

Comment: The last three parts of ActiveMQ JMS message ID should be consisted of `SessionSeq:ProducerSeq:MessageSeq`